# Select rows in a dataframe based on values of all columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I feel this question is very simple, but I am new in R, and I don't know how to solve it.
I have a dataframe df with 100 rows. The first column is Patient_ID and all the others are measurements of T cells over time. I want to select the rows (the patients) in which all the cell measurements are lower than 200.
My idea (maybe very complicated) was:

```
f200 = function(x){x "inferior to" 200} 


df2 = f200(df[,2:10])
```

select the rows where all elements are True, i.e., where product of all elements is equal to 1... But I don't know how to write this! Can you help me? Or tell me a simpler way?

Comment: Wow! I will try that. Thanks for the  lightning speed answer!

Comment: It is not working... I have a lot of missings. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @rr_silva yes, probably. Try `df[apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) all(x < 200, na.rm = TRUE)), ]`

Comment: or with `rowSums` , `df[rowSums(df[-1] > 200, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try with `Reduce` and `&`

```
df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(replace(df[-1], is.na(df[-1]), 0), `<`, 200)),]
#   ID col1 col2
#1  1   NA   24
#2  2   20   NA
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(ID=1:4, col1 = c(NA, 20, 210, 30), col2 = c(24, NA, 30, 240))
```

Comment: akrun, I got an error: Error: unexpected numeric constant in "df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df[-1], `<` 200"

Comment: Sorry, it was not the comma... There is still "unexpected numeric constant in..."

Comment: @rr_silva  Based on the data I posted, it is working. You haven't provided any reproducible example.  This should be faster than any `apply` solution

Comment: Please do not copy/paste answers with minimal changes from comments.

Comment: @RonakShah  I don't check your comments when they get updated.  If you wanted to post a solution, you should have done that.   Earlier, I find a `rowSums` comment which got deleted and find only the `apply` solution.   Also, I am using `!` and not `==0`

Comment: @akrun Your code is correct. It worked. But I must be missing something... I am sure that at least 3 patients meet that condition, but your code only finds one of them. I will try to understand what is the problem.

Comment: @rr_silva Please check the `str(yourdata)` and see if the columns are all `numeric`

Comment: @akrun No... Some colums are Character. How do I convert them? as.numeric(df[,2:18]) ?

Comment: @rr_silva try `df[2:8] <- lapply(df[2:8], function(x) if(is.character(x)) as.numeric(x) else x)` and then apply the code.  Also, check if there are `factor` columns or not?

Comment: @akrun No factor columns. Only chr.

Comment: @akrun Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' ... (Sorry for the extended discussion in comments... But I dont have enough reputation to chat)

Comment: @rr_silva  Please check the `str(yourdata)` You may have some `list` columns there

Comment: @akrun I guess so... str(df) gives me "Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  18 variables", and the list of variables where most are chr... They all should be numeric, except the first one (Patient_ID).

Comment: @rr_silva Try `df <- as.data.frame(df); df[2:18] <- lapply(df[2:18], as.numeric)`